# Tcl: How to get value from nested dictionary by list of keys

Tags: dictionary, tcl

I have difficulty accessing values in nested dictionary by using list of keys.

```
dict set testDict library [dict create NY [dict create section [dict create adult [dict create book cinderella]]]]
library {NY {section {adult {book cinderella}}}}
# I can access the value by:
dict get $testDict library NY section adult book
cinderella

# cannot access the same by list of keys in a variable
set keyLst {library NY section adult book}
library NY section adult book
set keyStr "library NY section adult book"
library NY section adult book

dict get $testDict $keyLst
key "library NY section adult book" not known in dictionary
dict get $testDict $keyStr
key "library NY section adults book" not known in dictionary

# The only not elegant solution I came up is using eval + list
eval dict get \$testDict $keyStr
key "adults" not known in dictionary

eval dict get \$testDict $keyLst
cinderella
```

While eval works in this instance - There must be better way to do this directly.

Any idea how to access nested dictionary values by key list in variable?

Comment: If it just code style, then you may ask it on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to expand the list (or string) into separate words.
`dict` does not take a `list` as an argument.

```
dict get $testDict {*}$keyLst
```

References: [dict](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/dict.htm#M13) ; [argument expansion](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/Tcl.htm#M9)

Comment: If we made key lists by default, working with arbitrary keys would become intensely annoying and (hence, because laziness) error-prone. It's a trade-off.

Comment: Thank you very much to the introduction to Tcl argument expansion - it is very convenient.

I understand the trade-off in the Tcl design - it is pity that the B.Welsh Tcl book predates dictionaries - I bet, he would have covered it. :-)